# Shear Text Transformation in Inkscape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, text, transform

Looking for a way to write text along an angle in Inkscape while keeping the vertical alignment straight. Illustrator has a "shear" transformation available this, but is anyone aware of an equivalent in Inkscape? Attached is an example of the desired result, from Illustrator.

[image: Example of shear from Illustrator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are several ways to do this in Inkscape.

Click two times on the text box to bring up the rotate/skew transform arrows. Don't do a fast double click here as that will switch to the Text tool (not what you want). Then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag on the middle-right skew transform arrows.

[image]

If you don't hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> the skew is based on the centre point

[image]

Note: This also works with any object in Inkscape, not just text.

If you want to do a numerical skew to a specific angle, open the Transform panel, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, and into the Skew tab.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!